# Archiving Xamarin Android App gives error XABLD7019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

VS 2019 Version 16.7.1, Xamarin Forms v4.8.0.1269

Worked previously, but archiving the Android App now fails (iOS OK).  I have updated the Android SDK.

The error is (logging set to diagnostic):

```
XABLD7019: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll.lz4' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AssemblyCompression.Compress(AssemblyData data)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.<AddAssemblies>g__CompressAssembly|138_1(ITaskItem assembly, <>c__DisplayClass138_0& )
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.AddAssemblies(ZipArchiveEx apk, Boolean debug, Boolean compress, IDictionary`2 compressedAssembliesInfo)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.ExecuteWithAbi(String[] supportedAbis, String apkInputPath, String apkOutputPath, Boolean debug, Boolean compress, IDictionary`2 compressedAssembliesInfo)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()
```

There is a file in that folder called 'Java.Interop.dll', but not one called 'Java.Interop.dll.lz4'.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Comment: Just noticed this...  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1120933/xabld7019-systemunauthorizedaccessexception-access.html

Comment: Changing the Linker settings fixed it.  But I suspect it will be fixed in VS 16.8, so I will await that before posing an answer.

Comment: I have had this problem, and setting `<AndroidEnableAssemblyCompression>false</AndroidEnableAssemblyCompression>` did not help. Apk was created, but app would not started. I solved it via starting Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: This bug is still present with the VS Version 16.8.0 Preview 1.0. (I wanted to check to build without AndroidEnableAssemblyCompression = false worked with 16.8.0). "XABLD7019: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll.lz4' is denied."

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE: upgrading to visual studio 16.7.5 fixes this.**

Updating to Visual Studio "16.8.0 Preview 1" **doesn't** fix this bug.

Workarounds:

1. add `<AndroidEnableAssemblyCompression>false</AndroidEnableAssemblyCompression>` to the release section of your csproj. (*I've confirmed this one works*) But it may result in increased apk sizes. (*UPDATE: doesn't appear to increase the apk size*)
2. Enable project Linking. (*unfortunately for some projects this is very hard to get working*)
3. Run Visual Studio as admin. (*I've confirmed this works on the Preview install, but wasn't prepared to do this on normal install*)
4. Add user modify priviligies to
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\`
   (This is kind of like (3) but less extreme. (*I've confirmed this works*))

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, the number 1 workaround worked for me. I'm using the Visual Studio for MAC.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the number 1 workaround.  It was building in VS2019 but failing at the command-line with msbuild

Comment: @GregC - I guess you were building release from the command line and Debug from VS?

Comment: @GregC - I figured the step that has this bug, is only done for release builds, but it's good to get confirmation of that.

Comment: I tried all of these options other than Linking and they didn't work for me. When I try the option 1, I get a blank UI. I have visual studio 16.7.7.

Comment: Then I uninstalled the app and ran it again in the Admin mode. Then it worked.

Comment: @sandeepani - given you VS number you weren't experiencing this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when preparing my android app for archiving in VS19 and found that setting the linking to 'SDKs assemblies only' resolved the issue for me, hope this helps someone.