# Xamarin Forms - Java.Interop.lz4 Access Denied Bug

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mobile

### Visual Studio 2019 - Xamarin Forms App Build Bug

I opened the linking feature in my Xamarin forms project and got this error while compiling

If I don't open visual studio as an administrator, it doesn't work.

How can I solve the error without opening Administrator

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll.lz4' is denied.`

Answer (score 2):

I too had this problem and i solve it by just opening Visual Studio with administrator rights

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported, you can track the status here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1120933/xabld7019-systemunauthorizedaccessexception-access.html

Switching to preview channel (8.8) solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using the answer for this question. [Archiving Xamarin Android App gives error XABLD7019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462141/archiving-xamarin-android-app-gives-error-xabld7019)

Its a workaround, but solved my problem while the update is not ready.

add false to the release section of your csproj. (I've confirmed this one works) But it may result in increased apk sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers

Fixed with vstudio 16.8 Update